# Would a Interplanetary, Totalitarian System Still Work Under This Government?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, government, religion

**To make a few limitations doctrine-wise:**

1. This religion/cult is headed by a single entity (claims to be God
   within a vessel) with various Lesser Gods acting as privy council
2. Promises salvation through creation of a new universe and life after death (reincarnation for the wicked, beautiful heavenly paradise for the faithful)
3. Has a variety of sub-cults (akin to the pagan Greek and Roman gods)

The head of this religion is a grandiose-type narcissist who established the cult to fulfill his desire for power and unquestioning admiration, and his theocratic empire is technically post-scarcity (most of the wealth goes to him and the faithful have to work very little with majority automation). Advanced space travel is possible in this universe; the distance from Alpha Centauri to Earth would take around 10 minutes. The population of this empire is around 400 billion.

The empire in question is the sole theocracy present in the galaxy and is one of the major powers. In the rest of the galaxy the religion is not so popular and is often persecuted against by foreign authorities. Most governments hold suspicion towards both the religion and the intentions of the theocratic government at large due to "heretical" religious radicals and independent pirate clans (both sponsored in secret by the head of the religion) that regularly terrorize their planets and disrupt galactic commerce, often for months at a time. Additionally, those who the head sees value in are often given special privileges and can be exempt from any policing outside of minor discipline. These people often head the sub-cults and are given the title of "demi-god".

**A few given assumptions:**

1. The head of the religion controls all information within his own territory, but does not have any method of controlling those who *travel* to spread his holy word or their access to information
2. The initial indoctrination method of the religion is very simple and benign in nature. Converts can hold direct, private conversation with any deity of their choosing at any point in time with a pilgrimage. The communities of the sub-cults are very accepting and are ordered under doctrine to actively improve or solve a convert's problems in the name of one's community cohesion and stability.

   Dissent of faith, however, is often punished by said community through doctrine-based methods like social deprivation, questioning of faith in or love for their community, and love for oneself to wear down 'strayers' and make them dependent on the love they get from their communities. And, since immortal souls exist no matter what, they either break and submit or become lost souls once entropy destroys everything while the faithful are saved.
3. Far more barbaric methods are used by medically-altered state inquisition bodies of respective sub-cults and communal spies (often posing as the equivalent of priests and pastors) that transmit recordings and alerts 24/7 to local inquisitions with hidden augmentations. Inquisitors utilize various forms of torture, brain modification with chemicals or medical devices, magnet therapy, or 'unfortunate accidents' to either break prisoners of faith or dispose of them. To not arouse suspicion, the respective communities of disposed thought criminals and the deceased in general are told to not mourn; instead they are to be joyous for the now-freed soul. During a small ceremony and funeral held in honor for the deceased, rituals are conducted to 'hasten their return' to another vessel or their transcendence to paradise.

In short, the theocratic institution uses torture and violence to police their populations in a way similar to that of governments like North Korea, Nazi Germany, Fascist Italy, the Soviet Union, and various totalitarian theocracies while maintaining a surface-level cosmopolitan acceptance of others. These governments did not stand the test of time for one reason or another.

I've narrowed down my question to this:

**Can totalitarian abuse and a neo-Orwellian police state keep order long-term despite far larger scale and population?**

Comment: Unfortunately, despite the pretense of intelligence from humans, yes, it would. The logic of those neural networks in the brain is fuzzy, not categorical enough; a human brain can hold conflicting beliefs without an immediate meltdown, as long as the beliefs don't need to be exercised in the same time. And the immediate reaction to a situation that put the two beliefs in immediate conflict is to attack the situation (or flee) and **not** the rational attempt to resolve somehow the conflict.

Comment: What competition do they have? If this is the extent of the civilisation then it can only break from inside, if it's not then what are the outside threats? In order to answer the question we would need to understand the destabilising influences and how your civilisation compensates for them.

Comment: @BLT-Bub Added outside threats (everyone else)!

Comment: @BLT-Bub also some internal ones (unaccountable elites who are free to effectively do as they please with little accountability)

Comment: FYI, circumventing our policies by deleting a closed question and posting it as brand new is not appreciated. You, like anybody else, have to use the edit function and wait that the reopening is voted by the community

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica The private notice I saw on the first post said that making a new post was okay with a different question, so I figured I'd save everybody the time and post a far more simplified question on a much more specific aspect of the original. Wasnt doing it to spite yall or nothing, but that's what I read it as. Either edit the question or make a new post with a different question (was how a polytheistic religion would grow/operate on a galactic scale and was too broad, shifted focus to whether or not space totalitarianism is feasible with the same example)

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica The original question i had was already different by the time i deleted the post, so I figured that there was no way for me to save it considering how up in the air it all was